# How is posterior distribution computed for various values of `Method` in the `Predict` function?

Tags: machine-learning

Assume I have some dataset to train a machine learning model on using `Predict` along with a test point `x`.

```
f = Predict[dataset, Method->myMethod];
f[x, "Distribution"]
```

What is mathematica doing in order to compute the posterior distribution? For some methods it's clear, for example Linear Regression, but for other methods such as Nearest Neighbors, there are several options that make sense for estimating a posterior distribution. The documentation doesnt seem to describe these details, unless I am missing something.

Is there some more detailed documentation? Or is there some way I can read the source of the implementation?